# Show that there exists $f ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^2 + f +1 ≡ 0 \pmod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $p ≡ 1 \pmod 3$ be a prime. Show that there exists $f \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^2 + f +1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.

I know the first few primes of this form are: $7,13,19$

So for example $p=7$ we have $2^2+2+1\equiv0 \pmod 7$ but this is the only example I can think of.

Perhaps this has something to do with showing $f^2\equiv f\equiv1\equiv0 \pmod p$? Then summing them into one congruence? Or perhaps this has something to do with Hensel's lemma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$f^2+f+1\equiv0\pmod p\iff (2f+1)^2\equiv-3\pmod p$ as $p$ is odd

Now, show that $-3$ is a quadratic residue of $p$ if $p\equiv1\pmod 3$

Reference : Quadratic reciprocity [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B13) , [2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html)

Comment: But the chances are that OP hasn’t seen Quadratic Reciprocity nor even the lead-up to it. Even though your answer is the one I would have given, I think I like @Zander’s suggestion a little better.

Comment: @Lubin, people working with modular arithmetic should taste the Quadratic Reciprocity someday.

Comment: @Lubin,I think his answer needs the concept of Modulo order, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee we are interested in $(\frac{-3}{p})$ since we let x=2f+1. the link says '' −3 is a quadratic residue modulo every prime which is a residue (mod 3)'' is this along the right trail?

Comment: @MathproofP., which primes are  quadratic residue  of $3?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the only quad. residues of 3 are numbers which are of form 1+3k or 0+3k?

Comment: @MathproofP., so, are on the right track?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $\frac{-3}{p}=1$ if $p=1mod6$ and if $p=1mod3$ then $p=1mod6$ for all p which implies the result?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8321/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-mathproof-p)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Observe $(f^2+f+1)(f-1) = f^3-1$

Comment: Further hint: look at the size of $({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z})^\times$ and consider torsion ($\leftrightarrow$ roots of unity in ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$).

Comment: @Zander $f^3-1\equiv0(p)$ if and only if $f^2 + f +1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ which I understand. but then I need to compare $f^3-1\equiv0(p)$ with my value of p and show that it is true which would prove the require result?

Comment: @anon can you explain this a bit further. what is torsion?

Comment: @MathproofP. I am using torsion here to refer to the finite orders of elements in a group. (Usually, a student learns group theory in abstract algebra before they learn about finite fields and polynomial rings and such. Is this different in your case?) In particular, since $({\bf Z}/p{\bf Z})^\times$ is cyclic (generated by $g$, say) and of order $3m$ for some $m$, then $f=g^m$ has order three, i.e. $f^3=1$ but $f\ne1$.

Comment: @anon could you help me with Zander's method first, then when I have some time I will research your one because I have not since those topics. I understand that all I need to do now is show that $\exists$ $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ st $f^3-1=0modp$ for $p=1+3k$ which proves result

Comment: @MathproofP. The idea, I believe, is to show that there is an element of order three in the group of units. Then that element $f$ will satisfy $f^3=1$ and $f\ne1$ hence $f^2+f+1=0$. But the existence of such an $f$ follows from group theory, since the group of units is cyclic of order $p-1$, and $p-1$ is divisible by $3$. (In any cyclic group of order $n$, for every divisor $d\mid n$ there is precisely one subgroup, which will be cyclic, of order $d$, and in particular any generator of that cyclic subgroup has order $d$.) Precisely which parts of this argument do you need help understanding?

Comment: @anon is it using something like cubic resiprocity

Comment: sorry just readin ur comment now posted too quick

Comment: @anon can we discuss this in a chat room somehow? I prefer real time if possible for you?

Comment: @MathproofP. Sure. If you meet me in the chatroom in about three hours (I have to leave now), we can discuss this and the $p$-adic stuff.

Comment: @anon thank you, I will contact you then

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\, $ If $\rm\:g\:$ has order $\rm\:3n = p\!-\!1\:$ then $\rm\:f := g^n\!\ne 1,\,\ f^3\! = 1\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,0 = f^3\!-\!1 = (f\!-\!1)(f^2\!+f+1)$

Comment: what is g? and what do you mean by its order? do you mean $f^3\equiv1mod(p)$ I need a bit more info to understand.

Comment: why have you specifically chosen 3n=p-1 as prde

Comment: @MathproofP. $\rm\ p\equiv 1\ (mod\ 3)\:$ means $\rm\:p = 1+3n\:$ for some integer $\rm\:n.\:$ You can choose $\rm\:g\:$ to be any element of order $\rm\:p-1,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:p-1\:$ is the least positive integer $\rm\,k\,$ such that $\rm\:g^k \equiv 1,\:$ i.e. $\rm\,g\,$ is a primitive root, i.e. a generator of the cyclic multiplicative group of $\rm\,\Bbb Z_p = $ integers mod $\rm\,p.\ $ Do you really know quadratic reciprocity (accepted answer) but not know these much simpler results?

Comment: 1: is g a polyn.? 2: do you mean $g^k\equiv1modp$? I know what order means. why can you choose such a g are you using fermat's theorem?

Comment: it's a nice proof, notice that $g^n$ is not congruent because n less than 3n. but can you answer my above comment to make it more clear

Comment: at the end you can divide out the (f-1) but why is (f-1) relatively prime to p in order to do this operation?

Comment: @MathproofP. Because $\rm f\ne1$ means $\rm f-1$ is nonzero hence invertible mod $\rm p$.

Comment: @MathGems how do you know such a g $\exists$ ?

Comment: @MathproofP. By a fundamental result of elementary number theory, e.g. see the [Wikipedia page on primitive roots mod n.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n)